# Sharepoint 2016 shows wrong username. How i can investigate further?

Tags: user-profile-service, security, 2016, kerberos

We have a SharePoint 2016 Farm with Kerberos Authentication behind an Apache Reverse Proxy. This worked fine the last months.

Now, when my colleague or I open SharePoint in the Internet Explorer the username of System accounts (SP_Crawler, SP_Warmup, SP_AppPool) appear at the top right of the window, instead of our personal accounts. Other users don't have these Problems at the moment.

In the user Profile Service entry my personal accountname was correct, but the DistinguishedName has changed to CN=SP_Crawler. Furthermore in the web application user policy the entry "Search Crawler Account" was connected to my personal accountname. The same happened in the policies of the user Profile Service.

We observed the following issues:

- When the first time my colleague saw the wrong username (SP_APPPool), she called me and I started my browser immediately and I also saw the account (SP_Crawler). At the same time the warmup scripts was running.
- The colleague and I script the creation of Team sites with powershell and we made the Installation with the AutoSPInstaller.
- Other user don't have these problems at the moment.
- After correcting the entries in the user Profile Service at some site collections the username shows my personal account and at other site collections it is still the SP_Crawler account, but with my permissions.
- We never use our personal accounts on the productive Servers, we have an administrative account for that.
- The personal account of my colleague has now SPDataAccess permissions on the Social, Profile and Sync Database.
- authPersistNonNTLM is False
- DistributedCache has been restarted several times over.

How can we investigate further, which changes caused this issue? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: How user profile sync configured, one way or import and export? What is the information in AD?

Comment: Thank your for the comment. We use the one way active directory import. My AD Account hasn't changed for two weeks and there is no Connection between my account an the SharePoint system accounts.